# how to control the frequency of network request calls for observables on retrofit

Tags: retrofit, observable

I am using retrofit and rxjava framework to make webservice calls to an api.

For this, i declare the endpoints as observables in the endpointinterface, and then i subscribe observer on this observable.

```
    Observable<JsonElement> call = mApiServiceRx.getUserInterestsObservable(mIDAccount);
    ConnectableObservable<JsonElement> connectableObservable = call.publish();
    connectableObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    connectableObservable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    connectableObservable.subscribe(delegate);
    connectableObservable.connect();


    delegate = new Subscriber<JsonElement>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() { 

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            // cast to retrofit.HttpException to get the response code
            if (e instanceof HttpException) {
                HttpException response = (HttpException) e;
                int code = response.code();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNext(JsonElement userInterest) {
           ....
        }

    };
```

My question is: by default, the observable is making multiple calls? is there a way to control how the observable chain multiple network calls? Or the observable does one network call per subsrciption?

Thank you for response,

Hakoum